# PDF opening inside a Current WebView Page

Tags: android

My application current view is In web view..inside which if user clicks on a pdf link.it should get installed on sd card and then available options for viewing must be shown ..if no Viewer available then a message should be shown

```
protected void onStart() 
{ 
      super.onStart(); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("URl"); 
      myWebView.setWebViewClient(
      new WebViewClient()
      { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 

            if (url.endsWith("pdf"))
            { 
               // do eet return true; } return false; 
       } }); 

       myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       /*WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();               \
       webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);*/
       }
```

Comment: when i click on the pdf link then nothing is happening...

Comment: i have added a intent for pdf viewing

Comment: What does Logcat says? Please paste the stack trace here.

Comment: sorry,Warren that's not possible...but i m a bit new to android world..i m not able to open the pdf on the current web view page..no action take place when i click the link...please give some suggestion..

Comment: @Alok listen buddy nobody is able to help you with such little info if you dont want to show code atleast post your log trace

Comment: 03-03 17:31:25.249: ERROR/dun_service(14103): Unable to open external port /dev/ttyHSUSB0 : No such device

Comment: When i click on the link...the logcat shows"Unable to open external port /dev/ttyHSUSB0 : No such device"

Comment: protected void onStart() {
   TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStart();
  myWebView.loadUrl("URl");
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
       
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {       
     if (url.endsWith("pdf")) {             // do eet          
      return true;         }       
     return false;     } });
     
    
  myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  /*WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
  webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);*/
}

Comment: i have put the code....please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Overide the function [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)()

```
youWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith("pdf")) {
            // do eet
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Forget that i even answered this question. Obviously you need read a book on [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: When i click on the link...the logcat shows"Unable to open external port /dev/ttyHSUSB0 : No such device"

Comment: i m able to do it.Anyone wants to know pleaselet me know.

Comment: @Alok you can answer your own question.